# How do I install pxssh? Module not found

Tags: python, importerror, pxssh

I get the error message module not found for pxssh.

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.12 with expect 4.0.1-1.

```
import pxssh
ImportError: No module named pxssh
```

Is pxssh included in pexpect

Comment: http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to import `pxssh` from `pexpect`:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
```

See the [examples for the `pxssh` class](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html#pxssh-class) from `pexpect` documentation.